# Find the closest element in a span of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a span:

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\
          0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
         \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\
          -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

find the closest element to 
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} p & q\\
          r & s\end{pmatrix}$$

Edit:

The inner product is defined as follows:
$$<A,B>=\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}b_{ij}$$
so the norm is just
$$||A||=\sqrt{<A,A>}$$

---

My attempt:

Since it's not an orthonormal set, I'm trying to use the least squares method:
$$A^TA\mathbf{x}=A^T\mathbf{b}$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is the closest element. However I cannot get it to work. I think I'm choosing A incorrectly?!
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
because now the above equation is not solvable.

Edit going through my notes I just realized that the above is only true for

### $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Second attempt

Since the I have the norm then I need to minimise:
$$||M-X||$$
where $X$ is the closest element in the span which has the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\-y&x\end{pmatrix}$$
$$M-X=\begin{pmatrix}p-x&q-y\\r+y&s-x\end{pmatrix}$$
And the norm is therefore:
$$\sqrt{(p-x)^2 + (q-y)^2 + (r+y)^2 +(s-x)^2}$$
I don't where to go from here?!

---

Attempt no. 3 as advised by Robert Israel

Let:

$$S_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\
          0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$S_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\
          -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$||S_1||=||S_2||=\sqrt2$$

So let

$$U_1 = \frac{S_1}{\sqrt2}\quad U_2 = \frac{S_2}{\sqrt2}$$

Then using:

$$<U_1,M>U_1 + <U_2,M>U_2 = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} p-q & 0\\
          0 & s-r\end{pmatrix}$$

Not sure if this is correct?!

Comment: For "closest", you *must* define a norm on the space of matrices. What will it be? BTW, your $\;A\;$ isn't even an element ofthis space.

Comment: @Timbuc I'm confused about what A should be and what it represents. I thought it was simply a matrix where each column represented a basis vector. At least that's how it works for $R^n$ but I don't know about $R^{mxn}$

Comment: Your two matrices are orthogonal, aren't they?

Comment: @sranthrop Yes but not orthonormal.

Comment: So make them orthonormal by appropriate scaling.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I know how to do that but then how does that help?

Comment: If $u_1, u_2$ are orthonormal members of an inner product space, the closest element to $v$ in the span of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is 
$\langle u_1, v\rangle u_1 + \langle u_2, v \rangle u_2$.

Comment: Exactly as Robert Israel says. If orthonormal then the closest elements are the projections.

Comment: @RobertIsrael OK I tried following that theorem but I got a strange answer?!